# Consequences of ortho effect on resonance

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, aromaticity

Consider any carboxylic acid with any group at *ortho* position. According to *ortho* effect, the resonance of the $\ce{C=O}$  with the ring is inhibited.

Is this resonance entirely lost? Or some little amount still exists?

Can resonance be present when the participating orbitals are not in the same plane?

Comment: Well, the "extent of overlap" of the orbitals will decrease but it won't completely vanish, so yes, there will be some resonance stabilisation.

Answer (score -1):

If they are off the plane due to steric effect,  then resonance wouldn't occur, hence the (-)R effect of - COOH group vanishes and hence "generally" acidity of the respective acid increases.

Comment: Wouldn't occur at all?

Comment: Also it took me a minute to realize OFF is not oxygen difluoride. Please don't use CAPS for emphasis (*italics* or **bold** is much better).